# ошибка в работе плагина gulp-sass

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, sass

пробовал устанавливать node-sass, не помогло в коде вроде бы все верно, в гугле не нашел ничего путного, пробовал делать по видео делал все точь в точь все работало, но в моменте конвертации sass в  css и установки gulp-sass постоянно вылазит эта ошибка, с чем связано?

````
let projectFolder = 'dist';
let sourceFolder = '#src';
let path = {
    build: {
        html: projectFolder +'/',
        css: projectFolder + '/css/',
        js: projectFolder + '/js/',
        img: projectFolder + '/img/',
        fonts: projectFolder + '/fonts/',
    },
    src: {
        html: [sourceFolder +'/*.html', '!' + sourceFolder + '/_*.html'],
        css: sourceFolder + '/scss/style.scss',
        js: sourceFolder + '/js/script.js',
        img: sourceFolder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,}',
        fonts: sourceFolder + '/fonts/**.ttf',
    },
    watch: {
        html: sourceFolder +'/**/*.html',
        css: sourceFolder + '/scss/**/*.scss',
        js: sourceFolder + '/js/**/*.js',
        img: sourceFolder + '/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,}',
    },
    clean: './' + projectFolder + '/'
}

let {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'), 
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
    del = require('del'),
    scss = require('gulp-sass');

function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: './' + projectFolder + '/'
        },
        port:3000,
        notify:false,
    })
}

function html() {
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function css() {
    return src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(
        scss({
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function watchFiles(params) {
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html],html)
}

function clean(params) {
    return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(css, html))
let watch = gulp.parallel(build,watchFiles,browserSync);

exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;```

**запуск gulp'a**

[19:38:43] Using gulpfile ~\desktop\zotus\gulpfile.js
[19:38:43] Starting 'default'...
[19:38:43] Starting 'watchFiles'...
[19:38:43] Starting 'browserSync'...
[19:38:43] Starting 'clean'...
[19:38:43] Finished 'clean' after 51 ms
[19:38:43] Starting 'css'...
[19:38:43] Starting 'html'...
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:

gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the `sass` and `node-sass` packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

[19:38:43] The following tasks did not complete: default, <series>, watchFiles, browserSync, <parallel>, css, html
[19:38:43] Did you forget to signal async completion?
````

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема. Честно не помню как решил. Посмотри тут https://github.com/MaxWatson94/Gulp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

или

```
let sсss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Comment: Мне понадобилось ещё выполнить `npm install sass gulp-sass --save-dev` https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/wiki/Update-to-the-latest-Gulp-Sass